# Combine Values From One Dataframe Into A New Column In Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, concatenation

Sorry, I'm stuck with on a basic task but I'm new to python so bear with me.

I'm trying to combine two values in a pandas dataframe into a separate column. I'm trying to combine the date values with the sport values. See code below:

```
date        sport       revenue
1/1/2019    baseball    100
1/2/2019    basketball  200
```

I want the final output to include the new column "date_sport_concat" w/concatenated values:

```
date        sport       revenue     date_sport_concat
1/1/2019    baseball    100         1/1/2019#baseball
1/2/2019    basketball  200         1/2/2019#basketball
```

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
df['date_sport_concat'] = df.date.astype(str) + "#" + df.sport
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
       date       sport  revenue    date_sport_concat
0  1/1/2019    baseball      100    1/1/2019#baseball
1  1/2/2019  basketball      200  1/2/2019#basketball
```